# How to create an ICalendar Feed that people can subscribe to

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, icalendar

I need to create a application in vb.net that puts out those cool `<<Subscribe to ical>>` links, which I can prefill with our events and milestones. While I have figured out I need to use DDay.ical.dll to get the events into a `.ics` file, I am not clear about how to get these to publish. I was thinking of using an RSS feed, but that defeats the purpose of using icals and would require a RSS to ICal converter,which seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 12):

You can host the .ics files with any web server such as IIS.

For example, if you create a web application at http://foo with virtual directory X:\Foo, and your VB.net app saves a calendar to X:\Foo\iCal\Calendar1.ics, others can consume the iCal feed at http://foo/iCal/Calendar1.ics.

Comment: Thanks for your response.

So, basically all I need to do is create a virtual directory and dump the ics files into it. Does Subscribe link just needs to point to this file? What if this file was updated later, how would I push the change of events to the user who subscribe to this icalendar?

Comment: Correct.

Yes, just have the link point to the .ics file.

iCalendar/ics (like RSS) is a pull technology, not a push technology. So the subscribers will periodically poll your server for changes. It should "just work."